# Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) i

Tags: fatal-error, cli, command-line, memory, magento2.3.4

I am getting error while running the cli commands,
I increased the memory_limit to 5G
[image]

Comment: You can use `php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: if you increase memory, please check `phpinfo`, it is reflecting or not.

Comment: It is reflecting in phpinfo

Comment: OK, did you tried command i shared ?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issues and I am tried same commands

```
php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:upgrade

php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:di:compile

php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento cache:flush

php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento cache:clean
```

//To run command forcefully

```
php -f bin/magento
```

//To run command with memory limit 4G

```
php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento
```

//To run command with max memory limit

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento
```

Thanks.